# ASP.NET DropDownList SelectedIndexChanged how to detect new value

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I understand that the event `SelectedIndexChanged` gets fired twice, first time with new value and second time with old value.

However, see my below code:

`<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListName" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" />`

```
Protected Sub DropDownListName_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DropDownListName.SelectedIndexChanged

    FetchDataForDetails(DropDownListName.SelectedValue)

End Sub
```

I tried putting breakpoint at statement and found that the function `FetchDataForDetails` gets called for new value twice. `DropDownListName.SelectedValue` is always new value, further nothing in `sender` or `e` that can show me old value. I am trying to call function only for new value.

Thank you

Comment: What happens to the Value that comes from the execution of this Function in `SelectedIndexChanged` Event?

Comment: Where do you  bind `DropDownListName_SelectedIndexChanged` to dropdownlist?

Comment: @evry1falls For now please ignore the value that gets returned, as my concern is about double execution.

Comment: @SelimYıldız see the code ```Handles DropDownListName.SelectedIndexChanged``` (you have to scroll horizontally) - that will do the binding.